# Sql get latest records of the month for each name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This question is probably answered before but i cant find  how to get the latest records of the months.

The problem is that I have a table with sometimes 2 row for the same month. I cant use the aggregate function(I guess) cause in the 2 rows, i have different data where i need to get the latest.

Example:

```
name        Date   nuA  nuB nuC     nuD
test1   05/06/2013  356 654 3957    7033
test1   05/26/2013  113 237 399     853
test3   06/06/2013  145 247 68      218
test4   06/22/2013  37  37  6       25
test4   06/27/2013  50  76  20      84
test4   05/15/2013  34  43  34      54
```

I need to get a result like:

```
test1   05/26/2013    113    237   399   853
test3   06/06/2013    145    247   68    218
test4   05/15/2013    34     43    34    54
test4   06/27/2013    50     76    20    84
```

** in my example the data is in order but in my real table the data is not in order.

For now i have something like:

```
SELECT     Name, max(DATE) , nuA,nuB,nuC,nuD
FROM         tableA INNER JOIN
Group By  Name, nuA,nuB,nuC,nuD
```

But it didn't work as i want.

Thanks in advance

## Edit1:

It seems that i wasn't clear with my question...
So i add some data in my example to show you how i need to do it.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL Server [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

```
select name, Date, nuA, nuB, nuC, nuD from
(Select *, row_number() over (partition by name, datepart(year, Date),
 datepart(month, Date) order by Date desc) as ranker from Table
) Z
where ranker = 1
```

Comment: well i need the get the latest record of each [name] in every month so i update the example to show you how i need to do it

Comment: I don't understand your select * does it need a From table or something like that? or i could i can just put this answer in my code and should work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT [name],MAX([date]) as [date] FROM Table1
            GROUP BY [name],YEAR([date]),MONTH([date])
) t2
ON t1.[date]=t2.[date] and t1.[name]=t2.[name]
ORDER BY t1.[name]
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just do an order

```
select * from tablename where Date = (select max(Date) from tablename)
```

followed by only pulling the first 3?

Comment: this is not going to work. The OP needs the record with the highest `Date` per distinct value in `name`